# Add button on windows search result of start menu

Tags: windows, start-menu, windows-search, regedit, macro-button

Is there a way, maibe from regedit, to add a button in the section pointed by the arrow of the start menu:

[image: Start Menu]

Because I saw that some programs do it.

Eg: I want to add a button named *Add link to desktop*, or *Open the parent folder in cmd*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are taskbar/start menu **Jump Lists** (tasks). Check out [Programming the Task Bar in Windows 7 with WPF 4, Part Two – Jump Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ff770767(v=msdn.10)) for an explanation of what that involves

Messing with forms code is probably more than you're looking for though. I did find a tool called Jumplist Extender that should basically do what you've asked about. See: [Create Custom Windows 7 Jumplists for Apps that Don’t Have One](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30131/create-custom-windows-7-jumplists-for-apps-that-dont-have-one/). I have not tried it myself.